# Can't update changes to tree, Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I try to use method `ReplaceNode`, replacement process is successful, but i can't save changes.
For example part of my code

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(Path)
CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetRoot();
MemberDeclarationSyntax firstMember = root.Members[0];
NamespaceDeclarationSyntax NamespaceDeclaration = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)firstMember;
NamespaceDeclaration =     NamespaceDeclaration.ReplaceNode((ClassDeclarationSyntax)NamespaceDeclaration.Members[i], lNewClassDeclarationSyntax);
```

How i must save changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root = root.ReplaceNode(lNamespaceDeclarationSyntax.Members[i], newRoot);
File.WriteAllText(tree.FilePath, root.GetText().ToString());
```

Need replace nodes in root...

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Furthermore, the reason why you need to do this is because Roslyn SyntaxTrees are immutable. I'll just delete my answer as you solved it already.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly cleaner than File.WriteAllText, just create a new syntax tree using the updated root node:

```
root = root.ReplaceNode(oldNode, newNode);
tree = SyntaxTree.Create(root);
root = tree.GetRoot();
```